# Receive calls Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8

I am looking for events that I can subscribe to receive notification of call events (outgoing or incoming) on Windows Phone 8. Also if possible try to get outgoing\incoming phone number however I couldn't find any Windows Phone API for doing this. Is there any way I can do using C# or Native C++ on WP8 platform? Is there any Private API I can use to perform this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One would wonder why you would want to do this..

However for obvious reasons Microsoft does not allow apps to get info such as incoming/outgoing calls. That is why you couldn't find  any documentation for it. So the answer to your question is going to be a **NO** I'm afraid.

Comment: Well, at least in Finland here we have an application that, when you receive a call from an in unknown phone number, searches said number in the company's database and shows you a possible match in seconds. I myself find it very useful. It apparently doesn't work on iOS or WP, though.

Comment: Hence the amount of malware on android

Comment: Hence you should check app permissions

Comment: Why add the extra step for the consumer when you can prevent this at the OS level

Comment: I'd say I prefer the diversity of apps and checking the permissions myself over the limitedness of iOS and WP. I do agree, though, that Android could use a feature where apps using such permissions would be disabled or warn by default, but _not_ fully and finally disabled by the OS.